# Growth of the $E_1$-magnetic energy if the number of connected components of the intersection $R_t \cap R$ increases exponentially with time $t$.

Tags: general-topology, electromagnetism

I would like to better understand this sentence taken from `Page 281` of [Topological Methods in Hydrodynamics By Vladimir I. Arnold, Boris A. Khesin](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Topological_Methods_in_Hydrodynamics/6hMuEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)

> Even for the $L_1$-norm, one can provide such growth of the $E_1$-magnetic energy if the number of connected components of the intersection $R_t \cap R$ increases exponentially with time $t$.
>
> Being $R_t=g^t R$, on what $R$ applied to a diffeomorphism $g^t=e^{\lambda t}$.
>
> Furthermore, the magnetic energy of a field $B$ with respect to the $L_d$ norm is given by$$E(B)_{L_d(M)}= \int_M B^d \mu$$ (where $M$ is a manifold and $\mu$ is a volume form).

My question is: Because if the number of connected components of $R_t \cap R$ grows exponentially then the magnetic energy of field B grows exponentially with respect to the $L_1$-norm?

Below is a picture from the book on `Page 280` which shows that the magnetic energy of the field grows exponentially to the $L_2$ norm.

> [image: Page280]